# integrating webpack with grunt requirejs project

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, webpack

I have a project which completely build with [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [reruiejs](http://requirejs.org/). For production build we are heavily dependent on [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

For JS modules, i have using [grunt requirejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-requirejs).

After evaluating [Webpack module loader](http://webpack.github.io/), i thought of trying it out in my project but not sure to what extent i should use it and how to implement the same.

Any reference point or example project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short, but very informative tutorial by Pete Hunt:
https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto

It goes through building a simple build script. After you get the hang of it, you'll be able to make your own scripts in no time.

If you use Webpack, it makes using Grunt & RequireJS redundant & unnecessary because Webpack can do all that for you. Plus, it will be tedious to maintain multiple build scripts in all these tools.

Comment: Then real question should be Grunt vs Webpack ?

Comment: Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, all these tools are meant to accelerate your development process. If you have a great build script in one of these and find no reason to switch, I'd recommend not switching at all. The only reason I switched from Gulp+Browserify to Webpack was because of it's hot reloading ability in React apps.

If you cannot convince yourself, then it probably means you don't need to. :)